# zend specified doctype is malformed errord

Tags: php, zend-framework, rdf, doctype, rdfa

so I was trying to add the RDFA doctype into zend by typing the following into my layout.phtml...

```
$doctypeHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_Doctype();
$doctypeHelper->doctype('XHTML1_RDFA');
```

so that I will be able to use the headMeta->appendProperty() function....but then it returned this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'The specified doctype is malformed'
```

how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bet your zend framework version is is before 1.11.2, because that error only comes up if the text passed to the doctype function isn't recognized.

It basically just goes through the array of recognized doctypes and if the text you input doesn't match any in the array, it checks to see if you have a properly formatted doctype string (to manually set the doctype). If your string doesn't validate it throws that exception.

You can see it in the doctype function in the code if you are curious: [Doctype Helper Source](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/branches/release-1.11/library/Zend/View/Helper/Doctype.php)